# Rails erb preprocessing not happening in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, erb, sass

For whatever reason, this first attempt at dynamic styling gets me a Sass::SyntaxError on the line below. It looks like the erb is not being pre-processed.

```
/* app/assets/stylesheets/variables.css.scss.erb */

$headerHeight: <%= '15px' %>;
```

It's in development mode. Any idea what could cause this?

Here are my configuration options relating to assets in case that helps:

```
# Application
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
config.assets.version = '1.1'

# Development
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scss needs quotes around the 15px part. So you will need to make it:

```
$headerHeight: "<%= '15px' %>";
```

Comment: Seems to work, but you definitely do not need quotes for assigning the variable to a constant, i.e. this works `$headerHeight: 35px;` so its interesting erb needs quotes

Comment: Sorry, to confirm, that won't evaluate. Check your css, it will just show '"<%= '15px' %>"' wherever you use that variable.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293878/sass-with-erb-wont-compile). Could you find a way to get ERB working on SCSS stylesheets?

Answer (score 0):

This is a `sass-rails` error, as discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/94).

I had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293878/sass-with-erb-wont-compile/14305274#14305274) and found out that the solution is by installing [`sass-rais-path`](https://github.com/quinn/sass_rails_patch).

This gets Rails to work SASS + ERB as expected. No need to use quotes.